# What is the alternative of flyway.setSchemas() method as this is deprecated?

Tags: java, flyway, deprecation-warning

I have multitenant application and to do DB migration i have to loop over each and every tenant schema and migrate it,but when I use `flyway.setSchema()` in my code it is giving deprecation warning.

What is the alternative for it?

```
List<String> schemas = getExistingTenants();

for(int i=0;i < schemas.size(); i++)
{
Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure().dataSource(dataSource).load();
                    flyway.setSchemas(schemas.get(i));
            flyway.migrate();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [`Flyway.setSchemas`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/Flyway#setSchemas(java.lang.String...))

> Direct configuration of the Flyway object has been deprecated and will
>   be removed in Flyway 6.0. Use **[`Flyway.configure()`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/Flyway#configure())** instead.

In your case it would be something like:

```
List<String> schemas = getExistingTenants();

for(int i = 0; i < schemas.size(); i++) {
    Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure().dataSource(dataSource)
                          .schemas(schemas.get(i)) // <-- configure schemas here using the
                          .load();                 // FluentConfiguration object's method
    flyway.migrate();                              // `schemas(String... schemas)`
}
```

See also: [`FluentConfiguration.schemas(String... schemas)`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/api/configuration/FluentConfiguration.html#schemas(java.lang.String...)).

Comment: It looks like the OP wants to migrate the schemas individually (each schema probably has the same structure), so setting `schemas` to the list (instead of individually), is probably not the right approach.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for pointing that out. I will clarify that. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

The proper way is to do this on the [`FluentConfiguration`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/api/configuration/FluentConfiguration.html) object just like you're already doing for the `dataSource` config:

```
Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure()
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .schemas(schemas.get(i))
        .load();
flyway.migrate();
```

This is also documented on [`Flyway.setSchemas`](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/Flyway#setSchemas(java.lang.String...)):

> Deprecated: Direct configuration of the Flyway object has been deprecated and will be removed in Flyway 6.0. Use Flyway.configure() instead.

See also [issue 1928](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1928).